# What does `cat-file` stand for in git?

Tags: git, cat

In git, what does `cat-file` stand for in this command?

```
$ git cat-file <...>
```

My first thought is "concatenate file" because the Unix command `cat` stands for "concatenate", but this doesn't correspond to the function of `git cat-file`.

Comment: It's common to use `cat` for only one file.

Comment: @Charlie Fish I know what `git cat-file` does, I just don't know what it stands for.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I thought it was commonly used for multiple files to string them together. http://www.techonthenet.com/unix/basic/cat.php

Comment: "One or more".  One is probably the most common.

Comment: @DietrichEpp OK.  It still stands for "concatenate" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)), so this isn't really relevant.  Do you know if "cat" in `git cat-file` also stands for "concatenate"?

Comment: Its name comes from the utility "cat".  It does the same thing, for one file.  I'm sorry, it seems rather obvious to me that since "cat" and "cat-file" do the same thing (for one file), that they would have the same name.  I'm not sure what else you would call such a program, since "cat" is so ingrained into our use.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I see now.  I'm just learning this stuff so these things are not obvious to me yet.

Comment: "I'm just learning this stuff" is a great attitude to take, in stark contrast with the earlier comment "this isn't really relevant".  We're not actually feeding you irrelevant information to throw you off the track, we're trying to answer your questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While [`cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) does stand for "concatenate", what it actually does is simply display one or multiple files, in order of their appearance in the command line arguments to `cat`. The common pattern to *view* the contents of a file on Linux or *nix systems is:

```
cat <file>
```

The main difference between `cat` and Git's [`cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file) is that it only displays a single file (hence the `-file` part). Git's `cat-file` doesn't really stand for "concatenate"; it simply is a reference to the behavior of the `cat` command.

> `git-cat-file` - Provide content or type and size information for repository objects

Technically, you can use `git cat-file` to concatenate files, if you use Batch Output mode:

> **BATCH OUTPUT**
>
> If `--batch` or `--batch-check` is given, `cat-file` will read objects from stdin, one per line, and print information about them. By default, the whole line is considered as an object, as if it were fed to `git-rev-parse`[1].

Comment: What is this "display"?  `cat` does not display anything; it writes data to stdout.  *If* stdout is associated with some human oriented device (eg, a tty), then perhaps you could say the data is "displayed", but that is a big assumption to make.  It is extremely common to write pipelines that use `git cat-file` as a producer, and that use case is (probably) far more common writing data to a terminal.

Comment: I'm being, perhaps, overly picky here, but the Linux (and UNIX) 'cat' command does indeed stand for concatenate - e.g., from 'man cat' on Linux: "       cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output".  If "git cat-file" does refer to the 'cat' command (which very likely is the case), then I think one can safely say that "git cat-file" does indeed mean "concatenate". (Sorry for the pickiness, but this bugs me [slightly] every time I read this answer.)

Answer (score 10):

to read the content ( or blob ) of a git object

```
git cat-file -p <SHA1>
```

to read its type

```
git cat-file -t <SHA1>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The main difference between cat and Git's cat-file is that it only displays a single file (hence the -file part)

A single file, ... or a `list` of single files.

> In the second form, a list of objects (separated by linefeeds) is provided on stdin, and the SHA-1, type, and size of each object is printed on stdout.
> The output format can be overridden using the optional `<format>` argument.

This is important when you consider [`git cat-file --batch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file#Documentation/git-cat-file.txt---batch), which prints object information and contents **for each object provided on stdin**.

See also [`git cat-files --batch-command` with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4689191/6309).

And With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the "`ref-filter`" machinery that drives the "`--format`" option of "[`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bda891e6647538693d6cec5d3085f1508fbb5f5f/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> and its friends evolves, to be used in [`git cat-file  --batch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bda891e6647538693d6cec5d3085f1508fbb5f5f/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file))</sup>".

See [commit bff9703](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bff9703f0a851d968a1ac60bc7cdc44e9a290652) (01 Jul 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit b9dee07](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9dee075eb07713a49922f7e1f90a6a9de5c5e5f), [commit e85fcb3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e85fcb355a38b5f01493efecdf0150a10ee471da), [commit 7121c4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7121c4d4e2877115fb372b3f147fad4cd1306751), [commit bd0708c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd0708c7eb8be43242180a1ea2a0f0acda7a4fbc), [commit 311d0b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/311d0b8e8e370bc9f6168af1f4e120d2b0975702) (26 Jul 2021) by [ZheNing Hu (`adlternative`)](https://github.com/adlternative).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bda891e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bda891e6647538693d6cec5d3085f1508fbb5f5f), 24 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9dee075eb07713a49922f7e1f90a6a9de5c5e5f): add %(rest) atom
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jacob Keller</sup>
> <sup>Suggected-by: Jacob Keller</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Hariom Verma</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: ZheNing Hu</sup>

> `%(rest)` is a atom used for cat-file batch mode, which can split the input lines at the first whitespace boundary, all characters before that whitespace are considered to be the object name; characters after that first run of whitespace (i.e., the "rest" of the line) are output in place of the %(rest) atom.
>
> In order to let "`cat-file --batch=%(rest)`" use the `ref-filter` interface, add `%(rest)` atom for `ref-filter`.
>
> Introduce the `reject_atom()` to reject the atom `%(rest)` for "[`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b9dee075eb07713a49922f7e1f90a6a9de5c5e5f/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup>, "[`git branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b9dee075eb07713a49922f7e1f90a6a9de5c5e5f/Documentation/git-branch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup>, "[`git tag`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b9dee075eb07713a49922f7e1f90a6a9de5c5e5f/Documentation/git-tag.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))</sup> and `git verify-tag`".

So both command should return the same result:

```
git cat-file commit refs/tags/testtag^{} >expected &&
git for-each-ref --format="%(*raw)" refs/tags/testtag 

basic atom: refs/tags/testtag *raw
```

Same for:

```
git rev-parse refs/mytrees/first | git cat-file --batch >expected &&
git for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(objectsize)%(raw)" refs/mytrees/first
```

---

Note that with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "[`git cat-file --help`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/008028a910b1bb820ad14b976665acf0f5cd4015/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file))</sup> is clearer.

See [commit 5fb2490](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5fb249021cfd1cf937a608610c330152936887e1), [commit 83dc443](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83dc443439ca0fdc9f99fc1ed623d0749ef637ed) (10 Jan 2022), and [commit 245b948](https://github.com/git/git/commit/245b948815048821e73edc1a2b4224eaa94a8fc0), [commit 9ce6000](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ce6000cb7a023e16ae1743df760edaae1c5ca1d), [commit 57d6a1c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57d6a1cf967e82c5cb51d0950c1ed7d1b0916fe8), [commit b3fe468](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3fe468075b7f0aa40f7a22a5a50e5e3e5fb2148), [commit 485fd2c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/485fd2c3dae9c05b43fe237f402274a59eb68e81), [commit 5a40417](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a40417876c8ec97e1f367a1638a558ec010e3d8), [commit 97fe725](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97fe7250753bae050b5d01c74ac0f38abb052845), [commit fa476be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa476be8f0963d4dd512eaf8ee23b3cd3986a500), [commit 68c69f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68c69f90c8e98b305d9effd1d25f6261a30b8e50), [commit ddf8420](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddf8420b59297b6b40246a33d8a1c760bedc93cc) (28 Dec 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 008028a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/008028a910b1bb820ad14b976665acf0f5cd4015), 05 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57d6a1cf967e82c5cb51d0950c1ed7d1b0916fe8): correct and improve usage information
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change the usage output emitted on "[`git cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/57d6a1cf967e82c5cb51d0950c1ed7d1b0916fe8/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file))</sup> -h to group related options, making it clear to users which options go with which other ones.
>
> The new output is:
>
> ```
> Check object existence or emit object contents
>     -e                    check if <object> exists
>     -p                    pretty-print <object> content
>
> Emit [broken] object attributes
>     -t                    show object type (one of 'blob', 'tree', 'commit', 'tag', ...)
>     -s                    show object size
>     --allow-unknown-type  allow -s and -t to work with broken/corrupt objects
>
> Batch objects requested on stdin (or --batch-all-objects)
>     --batch[=<format>]    show full <object> or <rev> contents
>     --batch-check[=<format>]
>                           like --batch, but don't emit <contents>
>     --batch-all-objects   with --batch[-check]: ignores stdin, batches all known objects
>
> Change or optimize batch output
>     --buffer              buffer --batch output
>     --follow-symlinks     follow in-tree symlinks
>     --unordered           do not order objects before emitting them
>
> Emit object (blob or tree) with conversion or filter (stand-alone, or with batch)
>     --textconv            run textconv on object's content
>     --filters             run filters on object's content
>     --path blob|tree      use a <path> for (--textconv | --filters ); Not with 'batch'
> ```
>
> The old usage was:
>
> ```
> <type> can be one of: blob, tree, commit, tag
>     -t                    show object type
>     -s                    show object size
>     -e                    exit with zero when there's no error
>     -p                    pretty-print object's content
>     --textconv            for blob objects, run textconv on object's content
>     --filters             for blob objects, run filters on object's content
>     --batch-all-objects   show all objects with --batch or --batch-check
>     --path <blob>         use a specific path for --textconv/--filters
>     --allow-unknown-type  allow -s and -t to work with broken/corrupt objects
>     --buffer              buffer --batch output
>     --batch[=<format>]    show info and content of objects fed from the standard input
>     --batch-check[=<format>]
>                           show info about objects fed from the standard input
>     --follow-symlinks     follow in-tree symlinks (used with --batch or --batch-check)
>     --unordered           do not order --batch-all-objects output
> ```
>
> While shorter, I think the new one is easier to understand, as e.g. "`--allow-unknown-type`" is grouped with "`-t`" and "`-s`", as it can only be combined with those options.
> The same goes for "`--buffer`", "`--unordered`" etc.

---

Still with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), optimize away `strbuf_expand()` call with a hardcoded formatting logic specific for the default format in git the `--batch` and `--batch-check` options of cat-file".

See [commit eb54a33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb54a3391bb3bdd6806ebffc21281eae8d9c0dca) (15 Mar 2022) by [John Cai (`john-cai`)](https://github.com/john-cai).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 889860e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/889860e1ad85340896f404155f2f16621ca6989e), 23 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb54a3391bb3bdd6806ebffc21281eae8d9c0dca): skip expanding default format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Cai</sup>

> When format is passed into `--batch`, `--batch-check`, `--batch-command`, the format gets expanded.
> When nothing is passed in, the default format is set and the `expand_format()` gets called.
>
> We can save on these cycles by hardcoding how to print the information when nothing is passed as the format, or when the default format is passed.
> There is no need for the fully expanded format with the default.
> Since `batch_object_write()` happens on every object provided in batch mode, we get a nice performance improvement.
>
> ```
> git rev-list --all > /tmp/all-obj.txt
>
> git cat-file --batch-check </tmp/all-obj.txt
> ```
>
> with HEAD^:
>
> ```
> Time (mean ± σ): 57.6 ms ± 1.7 ms [User: 51.5 ms, System: 6.2 ms] 
> Range (min … max): 54.6 ms … 64.7 ms 50 runs
> ```
>
> with HEAD:
>
> ```
> Time (mean ± σ): 49.8 ms ± 1.7 ms [User: 42.6 ms, System: 7.3 ms] 
> Range (min … max): 46.9 ms … 55.9 ms 56 runs
> ```
>
> If nothing is provided as a format argument, or if the default format is passed, skip expanding of the format and print the object info with a default format.
>
> See [this discussion](https://lore.kernel.org/git/87eecf8ork.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/).

---

Another difference between `git cat-files` and `cat:` **[mail-mapping](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap)**: the ability to map author/committer names and/or E-Mail addresses.

With Git 2.38 (Q3 2022), "[`git cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/87098a047be46ee69da056336109eee2139c1398/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file))</sup> has learned an option to use the **mailmap when showing commit and tag objects**.

See [commit ec031da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec031da9f97a2545601304b5ac1e93fee09425b4), [commit 66a8a95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66a8a95315edb3feba1190dcd89a208ae71bda61), [commit dc88e34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc88e349a297de6b7d0e21d81ac98f7816fcd473), [commit e9c1b0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9c1b0e38cbaf626034c3741cc68f7d706aee451) (19 Jul 2022) by [Siddharth Asthana (`edith007`)](https://github.com/edith007).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 87098a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87098a047be46ee69da056336109eee2139c1398), 03 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec031da9f97a2545601304b5ac1e93fee09425b4): add mailmap support
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: John Cai</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Siddharth Asthana</sup>

> [`git-cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec031da9f97a2545601304b5ac1e93fee09425b4/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file))</sup> is used by tools like GitLab to get commit tag contents that are then displayed to users.
> This content which has author, committer or tagger information, could benefit from passing through the mailmap mechanism before being sent or displayed.
>
> This patch adds `--[no-]use-mailmap` command line option to the `git cat-file` command.
> It also adds `--[no-]mailmap` option as an alias to `--[no-]use-mailmap`.

`git cat-file` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ec031da9f97a2545601304b5ac1e93fee09425b4/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt#L66-L71):

> ### `--[no-]mailmap`
>
> ### `--[no-]use-mailmap`
>
> Use mailmap file to map author, committer and tagger names
> and email addresses to canonical real names and email addresses.
> See [`git shortlog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog).

---

In that context, Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) adds: '`cat-file`' gains mailmap support for its '`--batch-check`' and '`-s`' options.

See [commit a797c0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a797c0ea042af697d82ad475b9f354c4a33a9047), [commit 49050a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49050a043bf767d370e7288cb6cca0ca21f13404) (20 Dec 2022) by [Siddharth Asthana (`edith007`)](https://github.com/edith007).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 319c3ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/319c3abadb047b37e33195f29486794501c8f83f), 05 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49050a043bf767d370e7288cb6cca0ca21f13404): add mailmap support to -s option
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: John Cai</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Siddharth Asthana</sup>

> Even though the cat-file command with `-s` option does not complain when `--use-mailmap` option is given, the latter option is ignored.
> Compute the size of the object after replacing the idents and report it instead.
>
> In order to make `-s` option honour the mailmap mechanism we have to read the contents of the commit/tag object.

`git cat-file` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/49050a043bf767d370e7288cb6cca0ca21f13404/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt#L48-L50):

> `<object>`. If used with `--use-mailmap` option, will show
> the size of updated object after replacing idents using the
> mailmap mechanism.

And:

> ### [`cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a797c0ea042af697d82ad475b9f354c4a33a9047): add mailmap support to --batch-check option
>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: John Cai</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Siddharth Asthana</sup>

> Even though the cat-file command with `--batch-check` option does not complain when `--use-mailmap` option is given, the latter option is ignored.
> Compute the size of the object after replacing the idents and report it instead.
>
> In order to make `--batch-check` option honour the mailmap mechanism we have to read the contents of the commit/tag object.
>
> ```
> git cat-file --use-mailmap --batch-all-objects --batch-check --buffer --unordered
> ```
>
> The command `git cat-file` can now use the mailmap mechanism to replace idents with canonical versions for commit and tag objects.
> There are several options like `--batch`, `--batch-check` and `--batch-command` that can be combined with `--use-mailmap`.
> But the documentation for `--batch`, `--batch-check` and `--batch-command` doesn't say so.
> This patch fixes that documentation.

`git cat-file` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a797c0ea042af697d82ad475b9f354c4a33a9047/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt#L94-L105):

> on stdin. May not be combined with any other options or arguments
> except `--textconv`, `--filters`, or `--use-mailmap`.
>
> - When used with `--textconv` or `--filters`, the input lines
>   must specify the path, separated by whitespace. See the section
>   `BATCH OUTPUT` below for details.
> - When used with `--use-mailmap`, for commit and tag objects, the
>   contents part of the output shows the identities replaced using the
>   mailmap mechanism, while the information part of the output shows
>   the size of the object as if it actually recorded the replacement
>   identities.

---

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cc7d7183f0a95ef5d7853106515db8b7c495997d/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file))</sup> updates the documentation .

See [commit cebfaaa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cebfaaa33332f26e40b99322b7d26f72a2ddcabb) (09 Oct 2023) by [Štěpán Němec (`stepnem`)](https://github.com/stepnem).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cc7d718](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc7d7183f0a95ef5d7853106515db8b7c495997d), 18 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`doc/cat-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cebfaaa33332f26e40b99322b7d26f72a2ddcabb): make synopsis and description less confusing
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Štěpán Němec</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Jeff King</sup>

> The `DESCRIPTION`'s "first form" is actually the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 5th form in `SYNOPSIS`, the "second form" is the 4th one.
>
> Interestingly, this state of affairs was introduced in [97fe725](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97fe7250753bae050b5d01c74ac0f38abb052845) (cat-file docs: fix SYNOPSIS and , 2021-12-28, Git v2.36.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/008028a910b1bb820ad14b976665acf0f5cd4015) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38062e73e009f27ea192d50481fcb5e7b0e9d6eb)) (cat-file docs: fix SYNOPSIS and "-h" output, 2021-12-28) with the claim of "Now the two will match again." ("the two" being `DESCRIPTION` and `SYNOPSIS`)...
>
> The description also suffers from other correctness and clarity issues, e.g., the "first form" paragraph discusses `-p`, `-s` and `-t`, but leaves out `-e`, which is included in the corresponding `SYNOPSIS` section; the second paragraph mentions `<format>`, which doesn't occur in `SYNOPSIS` at all, and of the three batch options, really only describes the behavior of `--batch-check`.
> Also the mention of "drivers" seems an implementation detail not adding much clarity in a short summary (and isn't expanded upon in the rest of the man page, either).

`git cat-file` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cebfaaa33332f26e40b99322b7d26f72a2ddcabb/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt#L6):

> git-cat-file - Provide contents or details of repository objects

`git cat-file` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cebfaaa33332f26e40b99322b7d26f72a2ddcabb/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt#L22-L29):

> Output the contents or other properties such as size, type or delta
> information of one or more objects.
>
> This command can operate in two modes, depending on whether an option
> from the `--batch` family is specified.
>
> In non-batch mode, the command provides information on an object
> named on the command line.

`git cat-file` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cebfaaa33332f26e40b99322b7d26f72a2ddcabb/Documentation/git-cat-file.txt#L31):

> In batch mode, arguments are read from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

add to @Matoeil answer, 
You only need to specify 5 characters of your `<SHA1>`.

```
$ tree .git/

.git/
├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
├── HEAD
├── config
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── pre-receive.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── index
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── logs
│   ├── HEAD
│   └── refs
│       └── heads
│           ├── master
│           └── testBranch
├── objects
│   ├── 1e
│   │   └── e2a78c0b40dd8e5c6b08e31171a3ce1e8d931b
│   ├── 29
│   │   └── 33b9017f79a27ff5ad3c4e154f67b44ae8482c
│   ├── 4a
│   │   └── 6a376085b9b3b8e6e73d2cdcc5281cf6915c58
│   ├── 4b
│   │   └── 825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
│   ├── 7e
│   │   └── 6965a8b2ff07da3e632a24ee024b9d2ec5245d
│   ├── ae
│   │   └── 853f7ece778281c463c1f0c603ef9d47a425b7
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
└── refs
├── heads
│   ├── master
│   └── testBranch
└── tags

17 directories, 28 files

$ git cat-file -t ae853
tree 

$ git cat-file -p ae853
100644 blob 7e6965a8b2ff07da3e632a24ee024b9d2ec5245d    fil1.txt
```

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6jD966jzlk) explain very well.

Comment: I believe the number of characters needed is dependent on the number of objects in your repo. Generally in `git`, you need to specify a number of characters of a SHA to ensure uniqueness, with a *minimum* of 4 regardless of repo/database size.

Answer (score 0):

git cat-file - The Cat(concatenate) command It reads data from the file and outputs the contents.

Comment: According to `man git-cat-file`, the full answer is not only contents. "git-cat-file - Provide content or type and size information for repository objects"

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just started trying to answer questions. Next time I will try to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: You can start already by editing this answer to improve it.